# Derby Database How To Store Year Datatype

Tags: sql, netbeans-7, derby

I am using derby database with Netbeans 7
   and want to store a data type as YEAR i.e. 2012,2013

don't  require the month and day , just the year

Any idea to either use the sql script or the Netbeans user interface will do.

thank you.

Comment: A year is just a number, so why not using a SMALLINT?

Comment: yeah that's true but was thinking of a way to discard the date and month and then utilise the portion for the year.

Comment: EXTRACT(YEAR FROM datecol)?